# Librosa Display Waveplot, why are they totally blue and flat?

Tags: wav, librosa

I followed [this example of Music Synchronization with Dynamic Time Warping](https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_music_sync)

However, when I do this:

```
import matplolib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display

x_1, fs = librosa.load('musicdata/slow_melody.wav')
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 4))
librosa.display.waveplot(x_1, sr=fs)
plt.title('Slower Version $X_1$')
plt.tight_layout()
```

and same for the faster version, I get this result:

[image]

I can properly reach the pitch classes of the wav files in chroma representations and there are no problems in the wav files.

I created the fast and slow versions of the wav files like this:

```py
    # Tone-duration sequence
    melody = [('E', 0.3), ('E', 0.3), ('F', 0.3), ('G', 0.3)]
    slow_melody = [('E', 0.6), ('E', 0.6), ('F', 0.6), ('G', 0.6)]

    melody_output = np.array([])
    # Construct the audio signal based on the chord sequence
    for item in melody:
        input_tone = item[0]
        duration = item[1]
        synthesized_tone = synthesizer(tone_freq_map[input_tone], duration, amplitude, sampling_freq)
        melody_output = np.append(melody_output, synthesized_tone, axis=0)

    # Write to the output file
    name = 'melody' + '.wav'
    write(name, sampling_freq, melody_output)

    slow_melody_output = np.array([])
    # Construct the audio signal based on the chord sequence
    for item in slow_melody:
        input_tone = item[0]
        duration = item[1]
        synthesized_tone = synthesizer(tone_freq_map[input_tone], duration, amplitude, sampling_freq)
        slow_melody_output = np.append(slow_melody_output, synthesized_tone, axis=0)

    # Write to the output file
    name = 'slow_melody' + '.wav'
    write(name, sampling_freq, slow_melody_output)
```

I get the tone frequencies from:

{
    "A": 440,
    "Asharp": 466,
    "B": 494,
    "C": 523,
    "Csharp": 554,
    "D": 587,
    "Dsharp": 622,
    "E": 659,
    "F": 698,
    "Fsharp": 740,
    "G": 784,
    "Gsharp": 831
}

Synthesizer is:

```py
    def synthesizer(freq, duration, amp=1.0, sampling_freq=44100):
        # Build the time axis
        t = np.linspace(0, duration, duration * sampling_freq)

        # Construct the audio signal
        audio = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)

        return audio.astype(np.int16)
```

Also, the input parameters are:

```
duration = 2
amplitude = 10000
sampling_freq = 44100
```

So, why couldn't I properly visualize the waveplots? What could be the reason that they appear like this?

Comment: Since you're using matplotlib, could you try using `plt.plot(x_1); plot.show() ` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong in the tutorial you are following. `librosa.display.waveplot()` doesn't plot anything by itself, you still have to call `plt.show()` to visualize it. From the official documentation, here's an example of it's usage:

```
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.util.example_audio_file(), duration=10)
librosa.display.waveplot(y_harm, sr=sr, alpha=0.25)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You can find more info here https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added plt.show() after plt.tight_layout() as you said. However, nothing has changed. I got the same plots in the previous image. But, I also tried with some other mp3 files and there was no problem with them. So, I think that the problem may be about the wav files that I have used, maybe?

Comment: ah i think the problem is that the examples you are trying to visualize are too long. One second of audio at a sample_rate of 48kHz is 48000 sample points per second. That might be why it is all jammed up. Try with a lower samplerate or a shorter audio file.

Comment: For the first wav files I tried, no. Actually, they were 2-3 secs. There was no issue with the other mp3 files as I mentioned, and they were 6-8 secs. So, interestingly I have a problem with the shorter ones. But I constructed that first problematic wav files with a python script. May this cause such an issue?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code. How do you create them? Could you add that code in an edit to your question?